# Expect response to be <3XX : redirect>, but was <200: OK>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, functional-testing

[rspec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MYRv.png)

```
  context "No user logged in" do
    it "redirects to login" do
      get :show, id: @user.id
      expect(response).to redirect_to("/login")
    end
  end
end
```

end
not sure where is wrong

Comment: Please show the `show` action of your controller and also how you define the `@user` var in your test.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EN609apM

Comment: Can you please also paste your `UsersController`, at least the `show` action?

Comment: can you post how is your controller?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it with this

```
  response = get :show, id: @user.id
  p response.body
  expect(response.body).to eql(#HERE THE BODY OF YOUR RESPONSE)
```